# syntax for string array migration

Tags: arrays, postgresql, knex.js

It seems postgres arrays are supported [knex #226](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/226). Is there syntax for a migration beyond raw sql? The [schema building docs](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-Building) don't mention it.

Presumably the raw sql datatype using the [postgres array docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/arrays.html#AEN6033) would be:

```
table.specificType('arrayfield', 'text[]')
```

But is there something like:

```
table.string('arrayfield').array()
```

Comment: What is `table.specificType('arrayfield', 'text[]')` supposed to be? Doesn't look like valid SQL.

Comment: My bad thought I'd linked. Knex querybuilder syntax http://knexjs.org/#Schema-specificType.

Comment: You wrote "raw sql" and linked to the Postgres 8.3 manual. That's not raw sql. And I don't assume you are using Postgres 8.3 ...

Comment: No `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.4`. And meant sql column type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, the `specificType` would be the way to go here, there's currently no OO interface for dealing with postgres specific types.